# How If condition works in office script

Tags: excel, power-automate, office-scripts

How can I write a if condition in office script to highlight the cells where "if date is equal to today date?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As I want to learn how to write if condition for a selected column in office script could you show me how if sb's birthday is passed(>= today) then clear that cell in the specific column?

Answer (score 0):

For the highlighting part you could use something like below.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Set range A1:A3 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("A1:A3")
    let conditionalFormatting: ExcelScript.ConditionalFormat;
    conditionalFormatting = selectedSheet.getRange("A1:A3").addConditionalFormat(ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.cellValue);
    conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFont().setColor("#9C0006");
    conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFill().setColor("#FFC7CE");
    conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().setRule({formula1:"=\"25/8/2022\"",formula2:undefined,operator:ExcelScript.ConditionalCellValueOperator.equalTo,});
}
```

For the check for for todays date you can probably use

```
let dateTime = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

Only thing which is missing is how you embed that into the formula1.